# Package "angular-gauge-chart" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^8.0.0" (extended), would install "10.2.4")

Tags: angular, angular-material

Please help how to solve the below mentioned issue while upgrading angular 9 to angular 10.

> Package "angular-gauge-chart" has an incompatible peer dependency to
> "@angular/core" (requires "^8.0.0" (extended), would install
> "10.2.4").

Answer (score 0):

Such error are saying that you'll install a newer version of `@angular/core` as the one that a library is requiring.

In your example, `angular-gauge-chart` weren't updated for o re 2 years and the latest accepted `@angular/core` was the 8.0.0

run the same cli command with `--force` at the end.

This will download the version you want from angular, and it may work just fine.

If it doesn't work, I would recommend

1. Making a PR with a new angular update to the library you're using
   If no answer
2. Make a fork and working with your fork
3. Choosing another library

Good to say that this will work till the angular v12, since ivy was forced on the v13.